# UIAlertview Delegate Method not calling in Child View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uialertview, xcode6.4, uialertviewdelegate

I have two controllers

`VC A` -> `Parent` and `VC B` -> `Child`

Alert view delegate method i.e

```
func alertView(View: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int){}
```

is declared in `VC A`.

When i display alert from `VC B` delegate method is not called on alert button clicked.

Comment: Add `AlertView` code to your question.

Comment: Add the whole code, how are you setting and calling delegate method?

Comment: func showAlert(){
var createAccountErrorAlert: UIAlertView = UIAlertView()
        createAccountErrorAlert.delegate = self
        createAccountErrorAlert.tag = sender.tag
        createAccountErrorAlert.accessibilityIdentifier = "ReportAbuse"
        createAccountErrorAlert.title = "Confirm"
        createAccountErrorAlert.message = "Testing Alert"
        createAccountErrorAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Cancel")
        createAccountErrorAlert.addButtonWithTitle("Ok")
        createAccountErrorAlert.show()
}

Comment: when i call showAlert() from child vc i.e VC B delegate method is not called

Comment: show the code of VC A , Parent VC B, and Child so that we can understand the problem better and tell you the solution..

Answer (score 0):

```
protocol alertViewDelegate:class {
    func alertView(View: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int)
}
```

Create an alert view delegate object in parent class VC A

```
weak var delegate:alertViewDelegate() ?= nil
```

Implement the delegate in VC B and Set the delegate object in VC B

```
let alertview = alertView()
alertview.delegate  = self
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting `AlertView` delegate to self, Self means `Child`, Change delegate to VC A.

```
alertView.delegate = self.parent?.parent
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow these step by step:

1. Create a **protocol** in your VC-B as:

   ```
   protocol AlertViewProtocol:class {
       func alertView(View: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int)
   }
   ```
2. Add a *var* in your VC-B class as:

   ```
   var delegate: AlertViewProtocol?
   ```
3. Use the delegate in any class method of VC-B to send the data to the receiving method (i.e. any method of VC-A), which is any method that adopts the protocol. Follow this pattern to use the delegate:

   ```
   delegate?.alertView(View: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int)
   // Above statement is like a method calling (on delegate var), use your parameters accordingly
   ```
4. Adopt the protocol in your recieving class (here, VC-A):

   ```
   class ViewControllerA: UIViewController, AlertViewProtocol {
   ...
   ...
   }
   ```
5. Implement the delegate method in VC-A:

   ```
   func alertView(View: UIAlertView!, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
       // Do your stuff
       // when you click on the designated button in your VC-B, this method will be invoked
   }
   ```
6. Set the delegate in VC-A where you are instantiating the VC-B object. In my case this is like:

> Here, `vcb?.delegate = self` is very important. If you forget to set the delegate property of the object with `self` the delegation process won't work.

```
    @IBAction func showVCB(sender: AnyObject) {
        let vcb: ViewControllerB? = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("viewcontrollerB") as? ViewControllerB
        vcb?.delegate = self
        self.presentViewController(vcb!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Hope, this helps you for understanding the process of how the delegates work.