# Swift Delegation - Use Stepper in Tableview Cell to Update Label in Separate Class

Tags: swift, protocols, delegation

I've been looking around stackoverflow a lot and reading a lot of different questions related to delegation but I haven't been able to work my problem out yet. I am trying to have my stepperAction (which is inside of a tableview cell) change a label in my BuyStats class every time its clicked. But so far, clicking the stepper has no effect. I think I need something in BuyStats.viewDidLoad() to set the delegate somehow but I'm not getting it. This may be easy for someone. Thanks for any help.

```
protocol SetRemainingValue : class {
func setValue(amount: Double)
}
}
```

//

```
class BuyStatsCell: UITableViewCell{

weak var setRemaining : SetRemainingValue?

@IBAction func stepperAction(_ sender: UIStepper) {

    setRemaining?.setValue(amount: sender.value)
}
```

//

```
class BuyStats: UIViewController, SetRemainingValue {

   @IBOutlet weak var spendAmount: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad(){

}

 func setValue(amount: Double) {

    spendAmount.text = amount

}
```

}

Comment: Where did you create your `BuyStatsCell` object?? You need to set `obj.setRemaining = self` somewhere in your `BuyStats` class. Otherwise who is the `delegate` of `BuyStatsCell` isn't defined and the message you are passing through delegation won't take effect. To know more about how these protocols and delegates work you can take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41689281/3687801)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using a dynamic `UITableView`, you might try the following inside your `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

1. When you init your cell with `dequeueCellWithReuseIdentifier`, cast it as a `BuyStatsCell` (maybe with `as! BuyStatsCell`) to get access to its class variables.
2. Set up the delegation with `cell.setRemaining = self`. The use of `self` assumes that your tableView's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is inside the `BuyStats` viewController class. If it's not, you would want to get the reference for your `BuyStats` object in the class where your tableView's code lives, and use that reference in place of `self`, like `cell.setRemaining = /*yourBuyStatsObjectReferenceGoesHere*/`.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, this worked! I figured out that I had to pass the reference twice to get it to my tableview code.